# Rails & Paperclip: Variable File Size Limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, upload, paperclip

I currently have a Rails app in which users of different ranks can upload files (via Paperclip).
I know I can set a global file size limit in the model, however I'm looking to enforce different file size limits depending on the users' rank.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest answer is that you write activerecord validations.
e.g. write following at model:

```
validate :some_name

def some_name
  errors_add(:file_file_size, 'error message') if file_file_size > 2.megabytes && user.rank > ...
end
```

Comment: I'm very new to Ruby On Rails - I'd assume this goes in the model? If it does go in the model - how do I use it?

Comment: yes, you put that in a model, and if uploaded file size is bigger than the validation, ActiveRecord don't commit this upload and rollback the database. If you want to think more about Rails Custom Validations, see here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#creating-custom-validation-methods